# Conditional calculation

Tags: android, android-studio

My code multiples the input number by 2 and displays the result.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText et1;
Button calc;
String val;
TextView r1;
int res;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
    calc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calc);
    r1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t1);
    calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String val=et1.getText().toString();
            res=Integer.parseInt(val)*2;
                    r1.setText(Integer.toString(res));
            }
        });}}
```

I want the number to be multiplied by 1.5 if its more than 100.
I am not being able to achieve if, else if. Is the String I used the problem. How could I be able to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
        String val=et1.getText().toString();
        float num1 = Float.parseFloat(val);
        if(num1 > 100){
            res = num1 * 1.5f;
        }else{
            res = num1 * 2f;
        }
        r1.setText(Float.toString(res));
        }
    });}}
```

You also need to change the res declaration to **float** if you pretend the multiple by 1.5 and keep decimal places. Else rreplace the floats I've entered with int

Comment: Thanks for the quick help.